# Rhino Mocks Returning a stub?

Tags: rhino-mocks

Is the following possible -

```
var stub1 = MockRepository.GenerateStub<stub1>();
var stub2 = MockRepository.GenerateStub<stub2>();

int returnValue = 1;

stub2.Stub(x => x.stub2Method(Arg<int>.Is.Anything).Return(returnValue).Repeat.Once();
Stub1.Stub(x =>x.stub1Method(Arg<int>.Is.Anything)).Repeat.Once().Return(stub2);
```

i.e. can a stub with expectations be returned from a stub?

In my code, when `stub2.stub2Method` is called from `stub1.stub1Method`, `null` is returned instead of `returnValue`.

Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry , I had a syntactical error , the above is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, though it may depend on what you are stubbing out.

As an example the following works:

```
public class Class1
{
    public virtual IClass2 Stub1Method()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IClass2
{
    int StubMethod2();
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var stub1 = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Class1>();
        var stub2 = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IClass2>();
        var expected = 1;
        stub2.Stub(s => s.StubMethod2()).Repeat.Once().Return(1);
        stub1.Stub(s => s.Stub1Method()).Return(stub2).Repeat.Once();
        var result = stub1.Stub1Method().StubMethod2();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }
}
```